# What is the difference between PIL's and OpenCV's resize

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-resizing, opencv

I came over the following issue: the resize functions of these two libraries behave differently. Here is a small test:

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = np.random.randn(10, 10, 3)
SIZE = (5, 5)
img -= img.min()
img /= img.max()
img = (img*255).astype(np.uint8)

# Display the initial image
plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
plt.close()

# resize the image in two different ways
img_cv2 = cv2.resize(img, dsize=SIZE, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
img_pil = PIL.Image.fromarray(img).resize(SIZE, resample=PIL.Image.BILINEAR)

# get the difference image and normalize it
diff = np.abs(img_cv2.astype(np.float32) - img_pil)
diff /= diff.max() or 1

# display results
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(16, 9))
axs[0].imshow(img_cv2)
axs[1].imshow(img_pil)
axs[2].imshow(diff)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

My question is now: why is this happening? Is the difference in the implementation (I didn't check the code in PIL or OpenCV yet) or am I using the functions in the wrong way?

Here are some example outputs: [Input image](https://pasteboard.co/JjKyraM.png) and [Resized images](https://pasteboard.co/JjKyLK2.png).

Comment: Your links appear not to work.

Comment: They work for me :-/ (tested a second ago)

Comment: I found an issue about this on GitHub: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2718